# How to upload 2 images to Firebase Storage at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

why doesn't this work? How do I get all the functions to run and perform it's task? I am trying to upload 2 images onto my firebase storage and get two download URLs for the images inside my firebase database (inside of post). And how do I get it to ignore the second image if it is not there?

```
  @IBAction func pickImage1(_ sender: Any) {


    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false
    selected = 1

    self.present(image, animated: true)
}

//Add didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo here
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        if selected == 1 {
            myImageView1.image = image
        } else {
            myImageView2.image = image
        }
    }
    else {
        //error
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func pickImage2(_ sender: Any) {

       let image2 = UIImagePickerController()
    image2.delegate = self
    image2.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image2.allowsEditing = false
    selected = 2

    self.present(image2, animated: true)
}




@IBAction func upload(_ sender: Any) {


    if let image1 = myImageView1.image {
        guard let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) else { return }

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image.png")
        storageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                return

            }


            else {
                let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString


                self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text, "Subtitle": self.subtitleText.text, "Article": self.articleText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text, "Tags": self.tagsText.text, "PostType": self.postType.text, "PostStyle": self.postStyle.text, "PostSize": self.postSize.text, "Download URL": (downloadURL)])

             return
            }



        })
    }

    if let image2 = myImageView2.image {
        guard let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2) else { return }

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image1.png")
        storageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                return

            }


            else {
                let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                let downloadURL2 = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text, "Subtitle": self.subtitleText.text, "Article": self.articleText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text, "Tags": self.tagsText.text, "PostType": self.postType.text, "PostStyle": self.postStyle.text, "PostSize": self.postSize.text, "Download URL": (downloadURL), "Download URL 2": (downloadURL2)])


            }

        })
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if the file already exists you want to call `storageRef.metadataWithCompletion`.

To unwrap an optional image you can just do

`if let image = self.myImageView2.image as? UIImage { // upload it }`

**EDIT**

Something like this

```
    if let image = imageView.image {
        guard let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else { return }

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image.png")
        storageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            // Handle it
        }
    }

    if let image1 = imageView1.image {
        guard let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) else { return }

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image1.png")
        storageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            // Handle it
        }
    }
```

Also make sure you're authticated with Firebase otherwise uploads will fails. Check console it will tell you if authtification failed.

**EDIT2**

This should do the trick.

```
func upload(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (String?) -> ()) {
    guard let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else { return completion(nil)}

    let storageRef = databaseStorage.child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image.png")
    storageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metaData, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to upload image")
        } else if metaData != nil && metaData?.downloadURL() != nil {
            completion(metaData?.downloadURL()!.absoluteString)
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}

func upload() {
    if imageView.image == nil && imageView1.image == nil {
        return;
    }

    if let image = imageView.image {
        upload(image: image, completion: { [weak self] (url) in
            if let image1 = self?.imageView1.image {
                self?.upload(image: image1, completion: { (url1) in
                    if url == nil && url1 == nil {
                        return
                    } else if url == nil {
                        self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text, "Subtitle": self.subtitleText.text, "Article": self.articleText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text, "Tags": self.tagsText.text, "PostType": self.postType.text, "PostStyle": self.postStyle.text, "PostSize": self.postSize.text, "Download URL1": (url1)])
                    } else if url1 == nil {
                        self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text, "Subtitle": self.subtitleText.text, "Article": self.articleText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text, "Tags": self.tagsText.text, "PostType": self.postType.text, "PostStyle": self.postStyle.text, "PostSize": self.postSize.text, "Download URL": (url)])
                    } else {
                        self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text, "Subtitle": self.subtitleText.text, "Article": self.articleText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text, "Tags": self.tagsText.text, "PostType": self.postType.text, "PostStyle": self.postStyle.text, "PostSize": self.postSize.text, "Download URL": (url), "Download URL1" : (url1)])
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    } else {
        if let image1 = self.imageView1.image {
            self.upload(image: image1, completion: { (url1) in
                if (url1 == nil) {
                    return
                }

                self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text, "Subtitle": self.subtitleText.text, "Article": self.articleText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text, "Tags": self.tagsText.text, "PostType": self.postType.text, "PostStyle": self.postStyle.text, "PostSize": self.postSize.text, "Download URL": (url)])

            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so should I put the database part twice in each of the handle it section?

Comment: Do you only want to upload `image1` if `image` is nil or fails to upload?

Comment: I want to upload image1 all the time and upload Image2 if it is there

Comment: This does exactly that. What is the `database part`?

Comment: I updated my question. I have the part where it gets the DownloadURL and add it into the post section of the firebase database

Comment: Okay I think I get what you mean. So what you want to do is add the download url's to the data base but if both images uploaded then add both download url's to that location? Am I correct?

Comment: Okay. I'll update my answer when i've put some code together.